# Best value odds

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate what is the best "value" odds between competitions and display a ratio/score that relatively indicates this. Each competition has a single prize but multiple tickets. I calculate the odds this way:

```
Total Tickets for Sale = 65
Odds Formula = 1/((Total Tickets for Sale/Tickets)+1)*100
Odds = 1.52% chance
```

Now if I had 2 competitions where the odds were the same, 1.52%, but the prize value was different, one was for \$100 and the other \$250.

How can I "score" that the $250 competition, while the same odds, is a BETTER win as a calculation?

Comment: Have you heard of "Expected Value"?

Comment: @DonThousand - I haven't, after reading about this I worked out how to get the data I needed. Thank-you!

Comment: The "odds formula" that you wrote is quite confusing. When you write "(Total Tickets for Sale/Tickets)+1" - is that a division? Are you dividing two numbers? I think not, because the result of $1.52~\%$ is obtained from
$$
\frac{1}{66} \cdot 100~\% \approx 1.5151~\%
$$
So perhaps the formula is just
$$
\text{odds formula} = \frac{1}{\text{number of tickets}+1} \cdot 100
$$
Am I right? Perhaps you can see why that way of writing the equation is confusing.
Next question: Why is there a $+1$ in the equation? Shouldn't the probability of winning be just one over the number of tickets?

Comment: Hi @MattiP. - yes you are completely right, thank you!

Comment: In that case, the result $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $p=\frac{1}{66}$ (or 65?). That is, we can think $X=0$ means losing and $X=1$ means winning. The probability density function of $X$ is therefore
$$
f(X) = 
\begin{cases}
p,& ~\text{if}~X=1 \\
1-p,& ~\text{if}~X=0
\end{cases}
$$
Can you continue from here?